# Uk Visa Refused need guidelines etc,,,

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan I applied for 4x Weeks UK family visit visa with my 6x years daughter and they refused, my refusal issue is same. I am going to quote my refusal letter.

1. You stated they you are employed with A----- company and Earning Rs. ____ per month in support of your application you have provided a latter from your employer. However  I am not satisfied that one document alone demonstrates that you have the employment status and earning claimed. You also state that your spouse is employer with ___ Company and Earning Rs. ____ per month in support of your application you have provided a latter from your employer However  I am not satisfied that one document alone demonstrates that you have the employment status and earning claimed with out further corroborating evidence. I note that you have declared no other personnel income, savings or assets. Based on the information provided i am not satisfied that your circumstances are as claimed and that you have demonstrated strong economic financial ties to Pakistan.
2. It is your responsibility to satisfy me that your circumstance in Pakistan are such that if granted leave to enter you will abide by all the conditions attached to any such leave and that you will leave the uk on completion of the proposed visit  but you have failed to do so. therefore I am not satisfied that  you are seeking a genuine visit or that you intend to leave the uk at the end of your visit  your application for visit visa has been refused  paragraph V4.2(a) and (c) I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to your visit including the cost of your journey. any cost relating to dependents and the cost of any planned activities. your application for visit visa has been refused under paragraph V4.2(e). 
   ,,,

These objections and reasons are not as like they thinking I have my bank statement and transactions including Rs. 4 lac balance I have transactions of my salary in statement and my husband recently employed he is also have his salary transaction in the same statement because we both using our joint account.

I just want to go Uk and meet my family for 4x weeks and I am with my 6 years daughter my husband is not going with us due to his job.

Now please guide me should I go for Administration review and provide them my bank statement because my visa rejected on 26 July 2016 I still have time period for administration review OR I should reapply immediately to remove all these objections and give them more evidences I mean bank statement and our pay slips etc? Kindly guide me what to do which way will work.. Your quick help and guidelines will help me.

Comment: Administrative review is for work permits and similar types of visas; it is not provisioned for visit visas.  Nor is there any other kind of review or appeal.  The only route is a fresh application.

Comment: Why is this question tagged Schengen?

Comment: I would like to mention the documents that I gave them with my and my daughters application 1. My Employer Letter 2. My Spouse Employer Letter 3. My Daughter School Leave Certificate 4. Our Marriage Certificate 5. My Husband's Passport Copy 6. My Original Passport 7. My Daughter's Passport 8. Our Family Life Style Photographs 9. Sponsors Letter 10. Sponsor Passport Copy 11. Sponsors Mortage Documents 12. Sponsors Property Documents which is in the UK 13. Sponsors 6 Months Bank Statement. These documents were submit with application and visa got refused in 15 days

Comment: Which new evidences should require to be added in reapply new application please guide me also how long will b safe to reapply as i got refused on 26 July 2016 and received passport on 2 August 2016. How much time will b good to reapply?